# Specify actual content-type of a uploaded file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, rest

I'm working on a blob upload service and I have this [code](http://pastebin.com/Un4Pb4XL) that persist uploaded meta-data in the Datastore and the actual bytes into the Blobstore.

I am having issues with the Mime-Type provided by the REST client (I am using the Rest Console Chrome plugin)

This is the mime-type that is passed from the client to the server:

```
Mime type:  multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytxCVEFIRjPB7YIq7
```

However the server needs to get the "actual mime-type", that is, for example image/jpeg, image/jpeg, text/plain, etc.

Using the App Engine API I need to explicitly provide the mime-type like this:

```
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(entity.getMimeType());
```

How do I specify this? Do I need to put another header? The files that will be uploaded will vary and that the file can be up to 50MB in size (If I remember that correctly).

Comment: Take a look at this [w3c document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). It explains how MIME types should be specified for files sent in a multipart form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Multipart" means that the data sent can have multiple parts, each with it's own mime type. Read about [handling multipart form uploads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms) on GAE.

You can use [`FileItemStream.getContentType()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemStream.html#getContentType%28%29)  to get mime type of each part.